# How to prevent that a ssh key that is used to perform git actions, is decrypted only once also when new terminals are opened subsequently on Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, terminal, git, git-bash

**Linux**

On my Linux system, I decrypt a private ssh key every time when I boot the system. Once booted I open a terminal and issue:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_some_key
```

and I am ready to perform git operations, like `git clone <git-url>`, `git pull -a` and so on. When I open another terminal and issue such commands again, no prompt will pop up that asks to enter the password of the encrypted ssh-key. In summary, on my linux system I only have to enter the password once.

**Windows**

On my work I have a Windows system. Once booted, I open [git-bash](http://www.techoism.com/how-to-install-git-bash-on-windows/) and issue:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

and `ssh-add ~/.ssh/private_key`, enter the password and issue git commands that are able to communicate with the git repository. In contrast to my Linux system, when I open a new git-bash and issue git commands, then a prompt appears that asks to enter the password. In summary, when the private key has been decrypted in a git-bash terminal, then it is possible to interact with git repository, but when a new terminal is opened the ssh-key should be decrypted again.

**What did I try**

I tried to use pageant. This first problem is that the id_rsa was not suitable. A new key had to be created using puttygen, but then it turned out that it will not be possible to use the ssh git url that starts with git@. It had to be replaced with the https url, but that is not what I want.

**What answer do I prefer**

I prefer an answer that satisfies the following criteria:

1. Ssh key has to be decrypted once when the Windows system has been booted and a terminal is opened to perform git actions
2. When a new terminal is opened, one could continue to interact with the git repository, i.e. no prompt will pop up that requests to enter the password.
3. I am not devoted to git-bash. If there is another terminal on windows that matches the first two criteria then it is fine by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

starts the SSH agent process (equivalent to Pageant), and creates typically two environment variables: SSH_AUTH_SOCK and SSH_AGENT_PID (at least on Linux, don't know if Windows git-bash makes any difference here; probably not).

If the SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable is set and points to a valid authentication agent socket, any process that can read the variable can use it. So you just need a way to have the value of this variable propagate from one git-bash session to another. The SSH_AGENT_PID variable is just a convenience, to allow the agent to be easily killed of if/when needed.

If you can store those environment variables (or even just SSH_AUTH_SOCK) in a file, so that your subsequent git-bash windows can read it, you can script it in this way:

Whenever a new git-bash is started (i.e. with the `.bashrc` script or its git-bash equivalent)

- check for the existence of the SSH agent environment variable file
- if the file exists:

  - read it
  - if the agent socket (and optionally the process) listed in the file still exists, use the variables as-is in your current session
- else (i.e. if the file was not there or its information was stale):

  - run `eval $(ssh-agent)`
  - create a new SSH agent environment variable file
- done!

Also, you might need to enter the SSH git URL in full form, that is, instead of just `git@server.name/project.git`, you should type it like this:

```
ssh://git@server.name/project.git
```

Technically, the form without the `ssh://` prefix is just a short-hand that is more convenient to type on the command line.